# Entity Framework Datagridview Sorting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Pulling the data from the database using the below code, I can't figure out how to put the pulled data into a sort-able datagridview? Using sortablebindinglist.cs

Thanks for the help!

I would love to  try the sortablebindinglist.cs but can't figure out were to insert it in the code or how to attach it to my data.

Any help would be helpful and educational!

Data from EF should be in a Datagridview and able to be sorted by clicking on the column headers

but I can't figure out the `sortablebindinglist.cs` and how to apply it to my code

```
namespace DepotLab
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {

        FileSystemWatcher _watchFolder = new FileSystemWatcher();

        DepotTestLab db1;

        public FrmMain(string str_val1, string str_val2, string str_val3)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = str_val1;
            textBox2.Text = str_val2;
            textBox3.Text = str_val3;
        }

        private void StartActivityMonitoring(string sPath)
        {
                _watchFolder.Path = sPath;
                _watchFolder.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                _watchFolder.NotifyFilter = _watchFolder.NotifyFilter | System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName;
                _watchFolder.NotifyFilter = _watchFolder.NotifyFilter | System.IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes;
                _watchFolder.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(EventRaised);
                _watchFolder.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(EventRaised);
                _watchFolder.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(EventRaised);

            try
                {
                    _watchFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {

                }   
        }

        //private void StopActivityMonitoring()
        //{
        //    _watchFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        //}

        private delegate void AddLogText(string text);
        private void TS_AddLogText(string text)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                AddLogText del = new AddLogText(TS_AddLogText);
                Invoke(del, text);
            }
            else
            {
                Txtb1.Text += text;
            }
        }

        private void EventRaised(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.ChangeType)
            {
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                    TS_AddLogText(string.Format("", e.Name));

                    break;
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                    TS_AddLogText(string.Format("", e.Name));

                    break;
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
                    TS_AddLogText(string.Format("File {0} has been deleted\r\n", e.FullPath));

                    break;
                default: // Another action
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




            Pan1.Visible = false;
            Pan2.Visible = false;
            CmbSystemType.Items.Add("DSX");
            CmbSystemType.Items.Add("DS2");




            db1 = new DepotTestLab();
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = mainBindingSource;
            db1.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            db1.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            mainBindingSource.DataSource = db1.Mains.Include("TestResults").ToList();

            StartActivityMonitoring(@"C:\Depot");          

            if (textBox2.Text == "User")
           {
               string ul = "User";
               Slabel1.Text = $"Current User = { textBox1.Text} { textBox3.Text } Access Level = {ul}";
               // BtnAddUser.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                string ul = "Admin";
                Slabel1.Text = $"Current User = { textBox1.Text} { textBox3.Text }   " +
                    $"                        Access Level = {ul}";
                // BtnAddUser.Visible = true;

            }
            Slabel2.Text = "";
            ShowTests();
        }


        private void ShowTests()
        {
            Main obj = mainBindingSource.Current as Main;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                if (obj.TestResults != null)
                {
                    testResultBindingSource.DataSource = obj.TestResults.ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await db1.SaveChangesAsync();

                MessageBox.Show("Your Data has been successefully saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void FrmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void CmbModuleType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CmbModuleType.Text.ToString();
        }


        private void CmbSystemType_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CmbModuleType.Items.Clear();
            CmbModuleType.Text = "";

            if (CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("Drawer");    //0
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("EPOD");      //1
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("Incubator"); //2
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("Pipette");   //3
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("reader");    //4
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("SID");       //5
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("Washer");    //6
            }
            else if (CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("Pipette");    //0
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("Reader/Incubator");     //1
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("SID");        //2
            }

            CmbSystemType.Text.ToString();
        }

        private void CmbModuleType_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CmbTestType.Items.Clear();
            CmbTestType.Text = "";

            if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 0 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0) //DSX Drawer
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("500 Plate Cycle");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Pipette Check");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("100 Plate Cycle");

            }
            else if(CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 1 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0)  //DSX EPOD
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Self test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("200 Plate Cycle");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Full Pipette test with Pipette S/N");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("10 hour 37 Degree");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("2 Hour 50 Degree");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("2 Hour 37 Degree");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("1 Hour 50 Degree");
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 2 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0)  //DSX Incubator
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Self Test and EPOD S/N");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("100 Plate Cycle");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("10 hour 37 Degree");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("2 Hour 50 Degree");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("2 Hour 37 Degree");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("1 Hour 50 Degree");
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 3 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0)  //DSX Pipette
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Tip Alignment");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Linearity");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("100 Plate Cycle");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("540 Level Detect");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("1080 Level Detect");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("625 Level Detect");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("1250 Level Detect");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Jim Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Pipette Collar Cycle Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Artel Volume Verification");
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 4 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0)  //DSX Reader
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Opsys MR Plate Verification");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("100 Plate Cycle");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Pipette Check Plate read");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("25 Plate Cycle");
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 5 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0)  //DSX SID
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("50 Cycles of Sample Rack 1");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("50 Cycles of Sample Rack 2");
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 6 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 0)  //DSX Washer
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Washer calibration");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("100 Plate Cycle");
                CmbModuleType.Items.Add("25 Plate Cycle");
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 0 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 1)  //DS2 Pipette
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Toolbox Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Matrix Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Artel");   
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 1 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 1)  //DS2 Reader/Incubator
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Toolbox Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Matrix Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Reader Top Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Reader Bottom Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Incubator Top Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Incubator Bottom Test");
            }

            else if (CmbModuleType.SelectedIndex == 2 && CmbSystemType.SelectedIndex == 1)  //DS2 SID
            {
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Toolbox Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Matrix Self Test");
                CmbTestType.Items.Add("Scan Test");
            }

            CmbModuleType.Text.ToString();
            CmbTestType.Items.ToString();

        }
        private void BtnADDNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Pan1.Visible = true;
            TxtSerial.Focus();
            Main c = new Main();
            db1.Mains.Add(c);
            mainBindingSource.Add(c);
            mainBindingSource.MoveLast();

        }

        private void BtnAddTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Pan2.Visible = true;
            Main c = mainBindingSource.Current as Main;
            if (c != null)
            {
                if (testResultBindingSource.DataSource == null)
                    testResultBindingSource.DataSource = c.TestResults.ToList();
                TestResult a = new TestResult() { Main = c };
                testResultBindingSource.Add(a);
                testResultBindingSource.MoveLast();
                db1.TestResults.Add(a);
                TxtWorkOrder.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Pan1.Visible = true;
            Pan2.Visible = true;

        }

        private void TxtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtSearch.Text))
                {

                    mainBindingSource.DataSource = db1.Mains.Include("TestResults").ToList();                  
                    ShowTests();
                }
                else
                {

                    if (RbSerialNumber.Checked == true)
                    {
                        var query = from o in db1.Mains.Include("TestResults")
                                    where o.SerialNumber.Contains(TxtSearch.Text)
                                    select o;

                        mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
                        ShowTests();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var query = from o in db1.Mains.Include("TestResults")
                                    where o.SystemType.Contains(TxtSearch.Text)
                                    select o;

                        mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
                        ShowTests();
                        RbSerialNumber.Checked = true;

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

                mainBindingSource.DataSource = db1.Mains.Include("TestResults").ToList();
                ShowTests();

            }

        }

        private void DgvMain_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                ShowTests();
            }
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxtSearch.Text = "";
            mainBindingSource.DataSource = db1.Mains.Include("TestResults").ToList();
            ShowTests();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question needs a bit more work, can you show what you have already?

Comment: I just posted the code  Thanks